# Is hyprocrisy the right word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm from Germany and I'm looking for a word that describes the following.

In General:
To tell someone something is wrong but doing it myself
Example:
Tell someone stealing is wrong(or even punish him/her) but steal something yourself

Hope you can help me and thanks :)

Comment: "Hypocrisy" (note the spelling) is one term that might be used, depending on the details.

Comment: It sounds like you want a verb. *Hypocriticize* is not an officially recognized word, but I think its meaning would be clear. But, one would usually here something like: *Don't be **hypocritical**. Follow your own advice.*

Comment: Being a bad example is not exactly the same as deliberate hypocrisy. I encourage others to look in their rear-view mirror at least every ten seconds yet I no doubt fail to do it all the time myself. I am not an absolutely perfect example, but am I a deliberate hypocrite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Hypocrisy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrisy)**, as a noun, fits your question.
**[Hypocritically](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocritical)** is an adverb.

> He hypocritically advised everybody not to steal, while engaged in stealing himself.

The person engaging in such activity is a **[hypocrite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrite)**

At times the verb **[dissimulate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissimulate)** may be used.

> William dissimulated his dislike of Mary by being very pleasant to her.

In the example in the question, **hypocritically tell** is the simplest solution:

> **Hypocritically  tell** someone stealing is wrong(or even punish him/her) but steal something yourself